# Views - PHP error: Allow memory size exhausted

Tags: 7, views

I'm suddenly experiencing the infamous "PHP Fatal Error: Allowed memory size of XYZ bytes exhausted" (Drupal 7.38)
This happened while trying to save changes to a view: I simply wanted to modify the field display order, nothing more, nothing less.

So, at the moment I can't see my website, even as an anonymous user, and even pages that aren't related to the view. Moreover, I can't access the admin panel.

I know this problem is usually related to module activation or other major changes, but in this case it is only a "minor change", related to an already existing view, a very simple one (and I have others - more complex), so even if I could increase the PHP memory limit, I think this would be only a workaround and not a "real" solution.

Comment: Just curious, what is your PHP memory limit ?

Comment: Ok, I restored the db dump and the website now is working.
But everytime I try to modify a view (e.g. simply for changing its description) or I try to insert a new one, when saving I get the PHP error again in file database.inc.
The only solution is importing the dump again, since simply truncating the cache* tables doesn't help at all.

Increasing the php memory limit doesn't help too: I tried to it set to 256mb, then to 512mb and I still get the message.

The site has been online for several months and I modified the views a lot of time in the past without any problem.
I'm stuck!

Comment: Ok. I found that the problem was the Boost module!
If I disable it I can modifiy the view normally!
So: disable Boost -> edit/save view -> enable Boost